# Check if file is uploaded before form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check wheather the user uploaded the file or not before clicking submit button through JavaScript/jQuery.

If a file is not uploaded, I don't want to allow form submission.

My html is:

```
<form action="/home/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >   
    Upload Image: <input type="file" name="image" />  
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is actually a bad design. Why would you upload a file even the form is not complete?

Comment: The required attribute is not widely supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
if(!$('input[type="file"]').val()) {
   // No file is uploaded, do not submit.
   return false;
}
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBsm/3/)

---

Using the HTML5 `required` attribute (**note**: only supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 5 (on Mac) and IE10):

```
<input type="file" name="image" required/>
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VLBsm/4/)

Comment: Comparing to zero here it's a bit confusing. It'll work because it's coercing to a falsy value and `""` is falsy. I'd just `if (! $('input[type="file"]').val())`

Comment: in HTML5 you can just use `required` on the HTML element...[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghBeD/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Updated, but mentioned browser compatibilty

Comment: @elclanrs True, I hashed out the answer without really thinking, updated!

Comment: @Zenith Safari 5 supports it on Mac's, but it doesn't provide any feedback like, 'Required file!' or anything. It also works fine on current versions of Opera. For browsers that don't support it, you can simply use the `formnovalidate` attribute. Either way, you'll probably need a feature-detection library like Modernizr if you're worried about compatability.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I thought formnovalidate wasn't supported in IE9 and earlier (and in Safari)?. Agree with the Modernizr part.

Comment: @lifetimes normally what is the best practice, do we upload the file before submitting the form or after ?